# Button not disabling if text missing in edittext

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-button

Could anyone tell me why my button isn't disabled when the text in the edittext is empty? I've tried to do this so many ways but it never  works! This is the simplified code I have at the minute.

**Code:**

```
public class MapStartActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    EditText mapName;
    Button NextPageStart;


    private TextWatcher textWatcher = new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            checkFieldsForEmptyValues();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    };

    private void checkFieldsForEmptyValues(){
        String s1 = mapName.getText().toString();

        if (s1.trim().isEmpty()) {
            NextPageStart.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            NextPageStart.setEnabled(false);
            NextPageStart.setAlpha(.5f);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_start);

        NextPageStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextStatLocBut);
        mapName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MapNameText);


        //Click Listener for button
        NextPageStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                mapName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Initially disable the button as EditText will be empty.


As per your code, if your Edittext is empty then your button is being enabled which should not be the case as per your question

**if (s1.trim().isEmpty()){}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add text watcher outside click listener like this

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_start);

        NextPageStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.NextStatLocBut);
        mapName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MapNameText);

        // To disable the button intially
        NextPageStart.setEnabled(false);

        mapName.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        //Click Listener for button
        NextPageStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // You can do some click action here

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: That has semi sorted the problem the next issue is that it is not doing it onLoad. When you add text and then remove it, it works but if you click the button straight away it still allows you to go through to the next activity.

Comment: then what it should happen..?

Comment: So when the activity launches the button shouldn't be clickable until there is text within the edittext. The when there is text the button can be clicked. Currently when the page loads the button clicks straight away and opens a new activity. This should only happen if there is text within the edittext

Answer (score 0):

In your code change these below lines only

```
 @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        String textFromEditText = mapName.getText();
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(textFromEditText)){
            NextPageStart.setEnabled(false);
         } else{
             NextPageStart.setEnabled(true);
         }
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't know why it's not working not for you, but I guess it should work fine. but you should learn about name convention first.

Comment: Very constructive input you pleb!